# Listing the content of the SFTP working directory

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, chroot, directory-structure, access-control

I am trying to create `SFTP Account` and I have the following configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
`Match group sftpgroup ChrootDirectory /sftp/ X11Forwarding no AllowTcpForwarding no ForceCommand internal-sftp`
to create a user I run the following command : `useradd -m username -g sftpgroup`  I've tried also `useradd username -g sftpgroup -d /sftp/username`
the problem is when I connect via an `SFTP Client` FileZilla For exemple, the remote site is pointed to `/` I  got this `Status:   Retrieving directory listing... Status: Listing directory / Status: Directory listing of "/" successful` 
[image: as showing here]
or If I have multiple users, I don't want to go search my folder among others, I want it to list `sftp/username` , the remote site must be pointed to `/username`

Comment: I may understood your question wrong. `ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u` will make `/sftp/fadwa` be listed as the remote's `/` when logging in as user fadwa. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think they want it to be displayed as `/sftp/fadwa` instead of `/` in the SFTP client.  Which won't be doable if they've chrooted as they said

Comment: @Hermann You get right, btw `%u` doesn't work it causes `Network error: Software caused connection abort Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: @ThomasWard no I just want the remote site \fadwa to be listed not I know `\sftp` can't be shown

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I've found so far is to add the working directory to the configuration file like this `ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /fadwa`,  Note that the working directory is  relative to the chroot, not the system's actual root (I took it from here https://serverfault.com/questions/686850/set-initial-remote-working-directory-in-sftp )

**BUT** in this case I should add a group of a user to the config file for every new SFTP account, is there any other generic solution ??